# Slow socket read() in proxy project

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing an http 1.0 web proxy for a school project. I have everything done and working, but my `read()` calls are very slow. I put a timer around the `read()` call (the one from C's stdlib). I see a bunch of 0s reads followed by one that takes 5-20s. This is on simple high speed sites (google, debian, etc.). On cluttered sites, things time out and the page never loads (cnn, yahoo, etc.).

I'm opening a socket to the server from the request's `Host:` line and writing the exact GET request from the proxied browser (firefox in this case). The write takes 0s. Here is an example request (the hashes are for visualization).

```
#########
GET http://debian.org/ HTTP/1.0
Host: debian.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive


#########
```

(Including the two `\r\n` lines at the end.)
Am I reading wrong? Or am I making a bad request? Loading the pages in chrome, or even using the GET request in telnet is lightning fast.

Here is the code that does the reading. The "Actual Read Time" output is usually something like 0, 0, ..., 0, 15.

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::string> SocketBase::read(bool toEof) const
{
  if (!this->isConnected())
  {
    Exceptions::raise<std::runtime_error>(__FILE__, __LINE__, "Socket is not connected.");
  }

  boost::shared_ptr<std::string> bytes = boost::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string());
  while (toEof || bytes->rfind(CRLFCRLF) == std::string::npos)
  {
    char buffer[BufferSize];
    time_t before = ::time(0);
    int rc = ::read(this->socket, buffer, BufferSize);
    time_t after = ::time(0);
    std::cerr << "Actual read time: " << after - before << "s." << std::endl;

    if (rc == 0)
    {
      break;
    }
    else if (rc < 0)
    {
      Exceptions::raise<Exceptions::ReadException>(__FILE__, __LINE__, ::strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
      bytes->append(buffer, buffer + rc);
    }
  }

  return bytes;
}
```

Comment: You are missing `Content-Length` header. Can you retry by sending this header? `Content-Length: 0` .. ?

Comment: I hate myself...I trimmed off everything but the GET and Host: lines. cnn.com loads in half a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the "Connection: keep-alive" line which tells the server you want to potentially have more than one request on the same connection.  The server will send the response and sit there idle awaiting further requests.  It'll eventually close the connection if it doesn't get one.  This is probably the behavior you're seeing.  If you want the server to close the connection after the request is serviced, ask it to do so via "Connection: close".  For keep-alive connections (and higher performance), you really ought to be using HTTP/1.1 and using the Content-Length header...